# iOS: Is there any way to open password protected Microsoft Office documents?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

In iOS 6, Apple added the ability to open password protected Microsoft Office documents in Mail.app. Is this functionality exposed to third-party developers in any way? When we attempt to open such a document using `UIWebView`, we encounter the exception: `CMTopExceptionDocumentIsEncrypted`. The stack trace looks like this:

```
0   MyTestApp                           0x000025a0 start + 0,
1   OfficeImport                        0x125ceb91 +[WMTop fillHTMLArchiveForOfficeData:fileName:xmlFlag:archiver:] + 603,
2   OfficeImport                        0x125e6f3a OIPreviewFillHTMLForDocumentData + 93,
3   OfficeImport                        0x125e6e48 OIPreviewProcessWithDataAndOptions + 154,
4   QuickLook                           0x08a8b7d2 OIGenerateProgressivePreviewForData + 267,
5   QuickLook                           0x08aafb1f -[QLBasePreviewParts computePreview] + 463,
6   QuickLook                           0x08a8fabb -[QLPreviewParts computePreviewInThread] + 315,
7   Foundation                          0x0078b0d5 -[NSThread main] + 76,
8   Foundation                          0x0078b034 __NSThread__main__ + 1304,
9   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x969a8557 _pthread_start + 344,
10  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x96992cee thread_start + 34
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears using `QLPreviewController` to render the content in place of `UIWebView` causes a password prompt to be displayed.